# Does RandomArrayLayer implement the reparameterization trick?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, implementation-details

I want to backpropagate through random operations (e.g. learn the mean and variance of a Gaussian random variable). I assumed that

```
RandomArrayLayer[NormalDistribution[#\[Mu], #\[Sigma]] &];
```

implements the reparameterization trick. And therefore a `RandomArrayLayer` backpropagates a gradient to the mu and sigma inputs.

However, initial experiments seem to indicate that no such gradient is propagated.

Am I wrong in thinking that `RandomArrayLayer` is differentiable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the answer is no. However, Mathematica's great support for NNs means we can create our own. For example, to create a network layer of random variables that are normally distributed:

```
NormalReparameterizationLayer[initialMeans_List, initialStds_List]:=Module[
   {\[Mu]Parameters, \[Sigma]Parameters, rl, rv, bnl},
   rl = RandomArrayLayer[NormalDistribution[0,1],"Output"->Length[initialMeans]];
   \[Mu]Parameters = NetArrayLayer["Array"->initialMeans,"Output"->Length[initialMeans]];
   \[Sigma]Parameters = NetArrayLayer["Array"->initialStds,"Output"->Length[initialStds]];
   rv = FunctionLayer[#Means+#Stds*#Random&,"Output"->Length[initialMeans]];
   NetGraph[
      {\[Mu]Parameters, \[Sigma]Parameters, rl, rv},
      {1->4, 2->4, 3->4, NetPort[3,"Output"]->NetPort["Params"]}
   ]
]
```

Say that we want to create a reparameterization layer that generates 2 normally distributed variables with initial parameters {0.0, 10.0} and {30.0, 5.0}:

```
rpl = NormalReparamterizationLayer[{0.0, 30.0}, {10.0, 5.0}]
```

[image]

Running this layer yields a realisation of the two random variables:

```
In[]:= npl[]["Output"]

Out[]:= {4.42441, 23.87}
```

The layer is automatically differentiable. And so we can plug this layer into any NN architecture and learn the parameters of random variables.